# Design class diagram OrderItem entity

Tags: class, class-diagram

I have an Order, OrderItem and Stock entity. Basically, an order is created and then items can be added to the Order. An Order can have more than one item. Each item in the order is where the OrderItem comes into play.

My question is this: What attributes should I have for the order item class?
Currently I only have the primary key to identify it.

Should I have anything else?

I do not need any of the details for the items in the order as all the details for each item is in the Stock class.

Here is am image of what I am talking about:

[image: Class Image]

Comment: maybe just post what you already have

Comment: it depends on your object model and your particular needs. if your orderitem only represents exactly one stock (I guess it's simliar to a product) than the orderitemId is good enough. but if you want to have like 5 boxes of juice as one order item (stock juice) than you would need the noOfStockItems. if you also want to model special offers like 'today 10% off' or 'buy 2 get 1 free' then you could add this information (like ordItemTotalCost) - if your offers are more complex then you may want to have this in a dedicated class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you 'need' to have will come down to wider requirements.  Some things you might consider though:

1. You've included identifiers (keys) on the classes.  You might also therefore want to include referentials (foreign keys) in `Order Item` - one each for `Order.ordId` & `Stock.stkID` respectively.
2. Do you need quantity?  i.e. how many of each Stock item in each order?  (e.g. 2 copies of "Lord of the Rings" if the stock items are books).
3. Date / time the order was placed?
4. Order status?  (Confirmed/Shipped/Delivered/Cancelled etc.)?

Those are common things to find in such a scenario; which apply will depend on what you need to achieve.

hth.